# 'For loop' within a function

Tags: javascript, math

I hope everyone is having an amazing day so far.

I am asking for help on an exercise that I am stuck on. I have gone through and researched all over but still am not getting it right.

The task is:

Create a for loop in which an iterator starting from 0 up to the iteratorMax value (not included) (the second parameter to your function) is incremented by 1. Add the iterator to num(the first parameter to your function) for each incrementation. you must return the number at the end of your function.

I was given this code to start with:

```
    function IncrementNumber(num, iteratorMax){
        //Add For loop here
    //return value here
    }
```

I have tried coding it a number of different ways but still not correct.

for example:

```
    function IncrementNumber(num, iteratorMax){
    for (let i = 0; i < iteratorMax; i++) {
            return(i);
        }

    }
```

I have tried to declare "i" but that seems to be incorrect also.

I really appreciate any help or hints to what I am missing or doing wrong in my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Declare `i` outside the loop, and then return `i` after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call return within the loop, the loop will only be executed once.
You need to move the return statement outside of the loop.
Whenever calling return, this will cause the current function to exit.

```
function IncrementNumber(num, iteratorMax){
  for (let i = 0; i < iteratorMax; i++) {
    num += i;
  }
  
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to you!!!! You solved my issue and I knew I was missing something but couldn't figure it out. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. :)

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you :) Please accept my answer as solution so it may help others too (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

For the `IncrementNumber(value, N)` method, when `value` is 0, this algorithm returns the result of the equation:

```
Total = N x (N-1) / 2
```

```js
function IncrementNumber(num, iteratorMax){
  for(let i = 0 ; i < iteratorMax ; ++i){
      num += i;
      console.log(`i: ${i}\tnumber: ${num}`);
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(`Result: ${IncrementNumber(0, 10)}`);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I really appreciate your help with solving my problem. You were right! I adjusted it and it was correct. Thank you so much again :)